# Aws ec2 - Unable to consume http server from a different machine on the same network

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2

Followed this tutorial to setup two ec2 instances:  [12 . Creation of two EC2 instances and how to establish ping communication - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3XlytYS6PU)

The only difference is I used a linux image.

I setup a simple python http server on a machine (on port 8000). But I cannot access this from my other machine; whenever I curl, the program kind of waits. (It might eventually timeout but I wasn't patient enough to witness that).

However, the workaround, I figured, was that you have to add a port rule via the security group. I do not like this option since it means that that port (for the machine that hosts the web server) can be accessed via the internet.

I was looking for an experience similar to what people usually have at home with their routers; machines connected to the same home router can reach out to other machines on any port (provided the destination machine has some service hosted on that port).

What is the solution to achieve something like this when working with ec2?

Comment: ***that port (for the machine that hosts the web server) can be accessed via the internet*** You have to define rule such that only the requests from other machine are allowed.

Comment: But security groups deal with public ip addresses. These vms although they have public ip addresses, I really don't want to use them for this purpose. I am expecting all internal traffic ports to be freely accessible. What would I need for that?

Comment: ***But security groups deal with public ip addresses.*** Really? I don't think so, you should be able to add private IP addresses. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules

Comment: @deostroll security groups are for all network traffic, not just public IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance is open to the internet because you are allowing access from '0.0.0.0/0' (anywhere) in the inbound rule of the security group.

If you want to the communication to be allowed only between the instances and not from the public internet. You can achieve that by assigning the same security group to both the instances and modifying the inbound rule in the security group to allow all traffic or ICMP traffic sourced from security group itself.

You can read more about it here:
[AWS Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-other-instances)